# To allow or disallow alphabetical content directory pages?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

We have a content that publishes fresh content 2-3 times a day. The site has category pages for tags and each alphabet. They both list the title with links to all the content within that category or starting with that alphabet respectively.

Should you allow the robots to index these pages specifically the ones that list titles of the page starting with each alphabet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the content is new, and you want it indexed, then you should specify the frequency in your sitemap(s).

As long as the content for each tag and alphabet character is not a duplicate of any other page, it's certainly not going to hurt your search results.

The downside is that if you have a great deal of content, then your server's resources may be taxed by all the requests from different robots. Therefore, you might want to limit which robots can index them (e.g., Google and Bing), while skipping other less popular search engine hosts.